# Django: Fixing an error in the payment view

Tags: python, django

I am trying to know the reason for getting an error which arises as a result of an exception in the views after making a payment. Noting the payment goes through with a successful message that the order has been placed but along with it comes another message saying that `A serious Error Occured. We have been notified.` which is related to the very last exception in the payment view

Here is the views.py:

```
class PaymentView(View):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # order
        order = Order.objects.get(user=self.request.user, ordered=False)
        if order.billing_address:
            context = {
                'order': order,
                'DISPLAY_COUPON_FORM': False
            }
            return render(self.request, "payment.html", context)
        else:
            messages.warning(
                self.request, "You have not added a billing address")
            return redirect("core:checkout")

    # `source` is obtained with Stripe.js; see https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment-charges#web-create
    # -token
    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        order = Order.objects.get(user=self.request.user, ordered=False)
        token = self.request.POST.get('stripeToken')
        amount = int(order.grand_total() * 100)

        try:
            charge = stripe.Charge.create(
                amount=amount,  # cents
                currency="usd",
                source=token,
            )
            # create payment
            payment = Payment()
            payment.stripe_charge_id = charge['id']
            payment.user = self.request.user
            payment.amount = order.grand_total()
            payment.save()

            # assign the payment to the order

            order_items = order.items.all()
            order_items.update(ordered=True)
            for item in order_items:
                item.save()

            order.ordered = True
            order.payment = payment
            order.ref_code = create_ref_code()
            order.save()

            messages.success(self.request, "Your Order was Successful ! ")
            # Email when order is made
            template = render_to_string("payment_confirmation_email.html", {'first_name': self.request.user.first_name,
                                                                            'last_name': self.request.user.last_name,
                                                                            'order': order})

            msg = EmailMessage('Thanks for Purchasing', template,
                               settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, [self.request.user.email])
            msg.content_subtype = "html"  # Main content is now text/html
            msg.fail_silently = False
            msg.send()

            # End of the email send
            return render(self.request, "order_completed.html", {'order': order})

        except stripe.error.CardError as e:
            body = e.json_body
            err = body.get('error', {})
            messages.warning(self.request, f"{err.get('message')}")
            # Since it's a decline, stripe.error.CardError will be caught
            return redirect("/")

        except stripe.error.RateLimitError as e:
            # Too many requests made to the API too quickly
            messages.warning(self.request, "Rate Limit Error")
            return redirect("/")

        except stripe.error.InvalidRequestError as e:
            # Invalid parameters were supplied to Stripe's API
            messages.warning(self.request, "Invalid Parameters")
            return redirect("/")

        except stripe.error.AuthenticationError as e:
            # Authentication with Stripe's API failed
            # (maybe you changed API keys recently)
            messages.warning(self.request, "Not Authenticated")
            return redirect("/")

        except stripe.error.APIConnectionError as e:
            # Network communication with Stripe failed
            messages.warning(self.request, "Network Error")
            return redirect("/")

        except stripe.error.StripeError as e:
            # Display a very generic error to the user, and maybe send
            # yourself an email
            messages.warning(
                self.request, "Something went wrong. You were not charged. Please Try Again.")
            return redirect("/")

        except Exception as e:
            # Something else happened, completely unrelated to Stripe
            # send an email to ourselves
            messages.warning(
                self.request, "A serious Error Occured. We have been notified.")
            return redirect("/")
```

here is the models.py

```
class Payment(models.Model):
    stripe_charge_id = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    amount = models.FloatField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Comment: can you print the actual error message in the exception block instead of your custom message? like - messages.warning(
                self.request, str(e))

Comment: yes, i used your code, the warning message appeared `'block' tag with name 'head_title' appears more than once`

Comment: check your template of try block, there clearly says block head_title appears more than once.

Comment: add your answer I will accepted it lead to fixing the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, try to print the actual message instead of a custom message.

```
messages.warning(self.request, str(e))
```

And fixed the error that occurs from your try block. Got to know from your comment

```
'block' tag with name 'head_title' appears more than once
```

Remove the duplicate 'head_title' block from your template.